# Facebook PHP SDK - 'next' param work with getLogoutUrl but don't with getLoginURL()

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, authentication, sdk

The 'next' param work with the getLogoutUrl() but don't with getLoginUrl(), what am I doing wrong?

```
getLogoutUrl(array('next' => site_url()))

getLoginUrl(array('next' => site_url(), 'scope' => 'email'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be redirect_uri for loginurl:

```
$params = array(
  scope => 'your_permissions_here',
  redirect_uri => 'Redirect_URL' //user will be redirected to this URL on both success or failure
);
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```